Cannot Remove Linked Project Reference Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 1 October 29 2024
Causing the issue
In testing how Project one can use a library module project two, I clicked a top bar suggestion “Code Insights unavailable (related Gradle project not linked)”
this links the projects which Android Studio cannot undo
linked projects no work

Project 2 module is compiled using Project 1 gradle settings. If library aliases and versions not identical: FAIL. for unspecified dependency or plugin versions: FAIL
Project sync produces mysterious gradle errors during script processing. This was never able to succeed
analysis will produces hundreds of issues analyzing two projects at once
kludging projects together is more opportunity for mysterious errors nobody else is experiencing, because nobody else is doing it

Cross-Project Library That Works
The conclusion is use the aar produced by project 2 library module in the file system, either directly or a copy as a dependency in project 1
Have each project open in a separate Android Studio window
How can the linked project be unlinked?
issues:

Analyze always runs for both projects with lots of errors
Project Tool window for Project 1 also displays project 2: duplicate gradle filenames with no project reference
if references are removed from .idea directory XML, Android Studio puts it back

grep -irHn project2NameOrDirectory .idea | less
FAILED
This project could not be saved
Solution was to restart from Empty Activity… again
